# What determines which event will run first?

Tags: events, minecraft, bukkit

I've created a test plugin as a science project to try and determine if 2 of the same event are called at the same time, which will be executed first.

```
public class TestPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }
    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
    public void event1(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event 1");
    }
    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
    public void event2(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        System.out.println("event 2");
    }
}
```

the output that the plugin produced are

```
[17:01:51 INFO]: event 2
[17:01:51 INFO]: event 1
```

if event1 is listed first in the class file, why is it that event2 is fired first?

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard to determine. Since `registerEvents` leads to the function `createRegisteredListeners` of https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPluginLoader.java

In there they use a `HashSet` to store the Methods of your Listener-class. So it is the pseudo random hash they give each method to store it that determines which event gets registered first.

I'm not sure but I guess that each and every time you register the events it's kind of random which gets registered first. This is why you should use different `eventPriorities` in order to determine which is called first.

If you really want to get deeper you have to tear apart the function `createRegisteredListeners` of the github-link I posted earlier in this reply. But I guess it woll never be totally certain because of the `HashSet` used in line `235` of the `JavaPluginLoader.java`:

```java
methods = new HashSet<Method>(publicMethods.length, Float.MAX_VALUE);
```

As Methods are added to the set it never is certain in which position in the RAM they end up.

I hope I could help you with this post even though it doesn't really answer your original question.